# Progamatically get Storage Account Connection String

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-storage, azure-storage-account

I want to upload and download data to Azure Blob containers of different storage accounts. I don't want to store the connection strings. I am passing the connection string to the BlobServiceClient.

```
                BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString, options);

                string containerName = "nameXYZ";

                BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);
```

I see a way to do this using a POST call, as shown in [this link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44515610/programmatically-get-azure-storage-account-properties)

Is there any other way to dynamically get the connection string?

I have the container name and Blob URL.

(I am using Azure.Storage.Blobs V12)

Comment: Could you please share your local `configuration` file ?

Comment: I don't have one. I don't want to store it in a configuration file as there are multiple storage accounts, and the keys rotate.

Answer (score 0):

OAuth is a better option for what you're trying to accomplish. Here's the documentation related to storage specifically: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad-app?tabs=dotnet